# Windows-1252 encoding to UTF-8

Tags: python, encoding, data-processing, iso-8859-1, windows-1252

I'm working with an old software to collect acoustic data from a manufacturing process. The file that was generated is an encoding unknown to both me and every application I've used to open the file. I've also used python to try and convert the file from latin1 to UTF-8... no luck.

Could anyone suggest an alternative way to convert this code to something sensible? Or at the very least, help me confirm what encoding I'm dealing with? much appreciated!

The output should just be numbers. Ideally separated into columns and rows but any advice is appreciated.

[encoded text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTKw8.jpg)

Comment: `The file that was generated is an encoding unknown to both me and every application I've used to open the file.` Why is the title of this question "Windows-1252 encoding to UTF8" if you don't know what encoding it is? `The file that was generated is an encoding unknown to both me and every application I've used to open the file.` Do you know that the file is text?

Comment: This doesn't look like a text file to me. It would also be strange to store acoustic data in a text format. What software produced this file?

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to determine the charset of the file. So we can either use [`chardet`](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) (python lib) or `find -bi $file` (Linux `file` command) to determine the charset. In practice, I have observed that `chardet` takes slightly longer processing time as compared to `file` command. Also, I'm executing my code in a Linux container so I don't have to worry about the availability of the `file` command. So for this reason I'm using the `file` command with the help of `subprocess` lib from Python to get the charset.

1. Function to run Linux commands via python. `run_cmd` will run the provided linux command and return a tuple of `stdout` and `stderr` in string format.

```py
def run_cmd(cmd: str) -> tuple[str, str]:
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        text=True,
        shell=True
    )
    std_out, std_err = process.communicate()
    return std_out, std_err
```

2. Execute `file` command and process the result from `run_cmd`. If a file is encoded with `us-ascii` it will return this `us-ascii` as charset.

```py
def get_charset(file: str) -> str | None:
    charset_cmd = f"file -bi {file}"
    std_out, std_err = run_cmd(charset_cmd)
    for result in std_out.strip("\n").split():
        if result.startswith('charset='):
            return result.split('charset=')[1]
    return None
```

3. Using the identified charset you can convert the file to `utf-8` or some other encoding.

```py
def convert_charset(file: str, from_encoding: str, to_encoding: str, inplace=False):
    output_file = f"{get_file_name(file)}.utf8.{get_file_extension(file)}"
    try:
        with codecs.open(file, 'r', encoding=from_encoding) as f_in:
            with codecs.open(output_file, 'w', encoding=to_encoding) as f_out:
                f_out.write(f_in.read())
        if inplace:
            shutil.move(output_file, file)
    except Exception as ex:
        log.error(f"Error occurred while converting charset of file={file} from={from_encoding} to={to_encoding}")
        raise ex
```

4. Now use the above command to convert your file.

```py
charset = get_charset(file)
log.info(f"charset: {charset}")

convert_charset(file, charset, 'utf-8', inplace=True)
```

This will convert the file into a `utf-8` encoded file.

*Note: I have used `log` to print messages. You can use print instead.*